# Skip a row GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I'm using the GridBagLayout on a JFrame and I'd like to be able to skip a row or two but have those rows show up as blank, and then have a button after those rows. I can't find any way in the documentation to do what I described, does anyone know of any way I can do this?

Comment: According to [How to use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) you can use `gridx, gridy` to set the row and column of the component you're adding?

Comment: Already using those, however I need to be able to skip a few y values and have them show up as empty space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out much cleaner than adding empty components... there is a `GridBagConstraint` named insets that allows you to choose the white-space between the component you're adding and the other components around it in any direction. Thanks for the answers though!

Answer (score 4):

Did you try adding empty components in the row you want to keep blank ? Like empty JPanels ? Or maybe invisible components.

Comment: This is what I do. You create a new `JPanel` called `fillerPanel` or something like that and give it the `Dimension` you wish it to fill. It's always worked great for me.