# Why in Java awt GridBagLayout, gridwidth or gridheight span one row or one column less than specified?

Tags: java, awt, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am writing a simple awt program with GridBagLayout in which I have four buttons arranged diagonally using gridx, gridy. When I set gridwidth as 3 it only span 2 columns and it ignores his own column. This is same for gridheight (it span 1 row less).

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

public class Second extends Applet{
@Override
public void init()
{
    GridBagLayout bl = new GridBagLayout();
    this.setLayout(bl);
    GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy= 0;

    gc.gridwidth = 4;
    gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

    Button btemp = new Button("Button1");
    add(btemp, gc);

    gc.gridx = 1;
    gc.gridy= 1;
    gc.gridwidth = 1;
    add(new Button("Button2"), gc);

    gc.gridx = 2;
    gc.gridy= 2;
    add(new Button("Button3"), gc);

    gc.gridx = 3;
    gc.gridy= 3;
    add(new Button("Button4"), gc);
    setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question but have you looked into the JavaFX framework? Comes standard on new versions of java and can be easier to write a GUI in (XML layouts!)

Comment: Your code is not setting gridwidth to 3.

Comment: @MeetTitan I am teacher and we have old syllabus

Comment: @VGR gridwidth is 4 but it spans 3 columns and it ignore his own column

Comment: A GridBagLayout has *flexible* rows and columns;  merely using four columns does not create four identically sized columns.  A column (or row) in a GridBagLayout does not take up any space, unless it has a component in it which defines its size.

Comment: @VGR Thanks for the correction, I've deleted my incorrect answer.

Comment: @VGR Yes I think it is taking first row height and first column width as zero if there is no other component in that row or column

Comment: *"I am teacher and we have old syllabus"* This is something I usually write to **students** who have such teachers. Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). ... Much the same could be said of AWT.

Answer (score 0):

The original code in the question renders like this:

[image: four buttons arranged in three columns]

And you want it to render like this, right?

[image: four buttons arranged in four columns]

Well...  I made that image by adding these lines after the `add(new Button("Button4"), gc);` line.  (The order in which you add `Components` does not seem to affect the outcome.)

```java
    //First, let us tell AWT to figure out the sizes of components
    //  it has so far.  If we do not do this, calls to getWidth()
    //  will return 0 sometimes!  It appears to be a race condition,
    //  but that's why this layoutContainer method exists.
    bl.layoutContainer(this);

    //Now, let us target the missing grid cell.
    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 1;

    //Let us put something in there, so the whole column has a
    //  non-zero width.  Using the width of an existing button
    //  is better than just picking some number of pixels.
    add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(this.getComponent(2).getWidth()),gc);

    //Let us adjust the applet window size (optional)
    this.setSize(this.getComponent(2).getWidth() * 4, 200);
```

Are you willing to stick an invisible component in that position in the grid, or do you need to solve this differently?

Comment: I can't see a good reason to use whitespace in a string to layout components in a GUI. The poster also says he's an instructor. I wouldn't recommend teaching students to hack around trivial problems. For example, what happens if you use a HiDpi display with your answer?

Comment: @MeetTitan We're working with AWT here.  These are the same classes I learned in Java 101 in 2001.  So, if bad things happen on high DPI displays, no one will be surprised.  Are you sure that it's possible to skip a position in a `GridBagLayout` without putting something in it? It doesn't have to be an empty `java.awt.Label`; what would you recommend?

Comment: In this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10949869/skip-a-row-gridbaglayout), a user suggests an invisible component.  `GridBagConstraints.insets` is also discussed, but, only allows you to set some number of pixels as a margin; it doesn't allow you to skip a cell in the grid and certainly isn't high-DPI compatible. :(

Comment: I wouldn't recommend a `GridbagLayout`, but that is outside the parameters of the original question; and StackOverflow doesn't pay me enough to think about every solution.

Comment: OK, it's far less hacky now!  I agree that the original question is looking for a `GridBagLayout` solution.  I do not think one exists that doesn't involve putting a spacer in.  So long as there are no components in that first column (and the column-spanning Button1 doesn't count!), the first column will be zero-width, resulting in the 'missing column' behavior we see.  I put research into this answer and I hope that is noticed and appreciated.